# N-dimensional vectors in PostgreSQL Spatial Index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, spatial-index, r-tree

I have many 8-dimensional vectors. And I want to construct on them a R-tree ('USING gist' in PostgreSQL). But I have got stucked at the choice of the correct geometrical type.

Whether the 'path' type (each vector number as x and y coords of path) will be suitable for my purposes? Or I should use additional extension? Or I follow in the incorrect direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your data fits into main memory, use a dedicated analysis tool like ELKI instead of a SQL database. In my experience, the performance of gist is not very good; it only pays off if you need persistence and transactions.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Thanks for advice! I used this program. But I have wanted to estimate parameters for DBSCAN, using k-dist from original article. I didn't think that I will have such difficulties. And ELKI also uses r-trees unlike scikit?

Comment: ELKI has r-trees and many other indexes (I mostly use cover trees), and a class (something with knn) that you can use to estimate the epsilon parameter. Or you use OPTICS.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Yes! KNNDistancesSampler - what is necessary! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Depending on how many 'many vectors' are, you may also look at the ELKI-phtree plug-in, it should work nicely with a million vectors or more.